# Tag creation request: smart-previews

Tags: discussion, tags

I just [asked (and answered) a question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/121137) that was related to Lightroom smart previews, and there are lots of [other questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=smart+preview) about Lightroom smart previews on Photography Stack Exchange. Do you think we should create a tag for Lightroom smart previews?

Comment: Modify your search to ["smart preview is:question"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=smart+preview+is%3Aquestion) to just get individual questions that ask  about or mention smart previews, and the results list goes down to 17.

Comment: @scottbb Oh, OK, thanks! I guess my original search also searched for answers of such questions, so it look like there were a lot of questions that mention smart previews.